# list object has no attribute split and lots of other error

Tags: python, list, random, append

Im trying to ask the user to set a minimum and max value and then ask how many random numbers they want to put in the list in the range they set. Im really new to programming and have no clue if im even close to doing this correctly.

```
import random

liste_x = []
liste_y = []

def random_pkt():
    length = input("What should minimum and max value be? write as: x,y. or exit")
    while (length != "exit"):
        length = length.split(",")
        minimum = int(length[0])
        maks = int(length[1])
    datapoint = input("How many random data do you want? or exit")
    while (datapoint != "exit"):
        for i in range(datapoint):
            liste_x.append(str(random.randint(minimum, maks)))
            liste_y.append(str(random.randint(minimum, maks)))
        datapoint = input("How many random data do you want? or exit")
    return liste_x, liste_y

random_pkt()
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: I guess you are getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'?

Answer (score 0):

```py
while (length != "exit"):
    length = length.split(",")
    minimum = int(length[0])
    maks = int(length[1])
```

In the first iteration of this loop `length` is a string (returned from `input`). Then you do `length = length.split(",")` - `length` is now a list.

In the second iteration, `length` is a list, `.split` does not exist in a `list` data type. Also it's absolutely useless to try and compare a list to the string `"exit"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code:

```
rand_list = [random.randint(min, max) for _ in range(number)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if instead of while:

```py
    import random
    
    liste_x = []
    liste_y = []
    
    def random_pkt():
        length = input("What should minimum and max value be? write as: x,y. or exit")
        if (length == "exit"):
            return None
        length = length.split(",")
        minimum = int(length[0])
        maks = int(length[1])
        datapoint = input("How many random data do you want? or exit")
        if (datapoint == "exit"):
            return None
        for i in range(int(datapoint)):
            liste_x.append(str(random.randint(minimum, maks)))
            liste_y.append(str(random.randint(minimum, maks)))
            
        return liste_x, liste_y
    
    random_pkt()
```

Comment: Line 14, you are looping in the range of a string?

Comment: This will not work. If the users types in exit, what happens?

Comment: Hint: will user input 'exit' always exit the application with this approach?

Comment: Yes, now it is possible to exit in both user inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
    
liste_x = []
liste_y = []

def random_pkt():
    length = input("What should minimum and max value be? write as: x,y. or exit")

    if (length == "exit"):
        return ""

    length = length.split(",")
    minimum = int(length[0])
    maks = int(length[1])
    datapoint = input("How many random data do you want? or exit")

    if (datapoint == "exit"):
        return ""

    for i in range(int(datapoint)):
        liste_x.append(str(random.randint(minimum, maks)))
        liste_y.append(str(random.randint(minimum, maks)))
        
    return liste_x, liste_y

print(random_pkt())
```

Runs with no exit:

```
What should minimum and max value be? write as: x,y. or exit5,9
How many random data do you want? or exit5
(['9', '6', '7', '8', '7'], ['7', '7', '5', '9', '9'])
```

Runs with exit:

```
What should minimum and max value be? write as: x,y. or exitexit
>
```